# Google Email / Heroku Hosting / Email Delivery Failure

Tags: heroku, gmail, mail-server

I hope someone out there can tell me if I have something configured wrong or if this is a Heroku bug.

When I email someone at a University, the email somehow comes in with a herokuapp extension in the email address that does not really exist. Then when people try to reply, it bounces back because that email doesnt exist. An example of this is below.

I'm hoping I have a CName configured wrong or something. I am not using A records, all CName records. My first CNAME record is an @ record with the value of challengage.herokuapp.com.

Let me know if you can help! Much appreciated.

```
---------- Forwarded message ----------

    From: David DiMaggio 
Date: Monday, July 15, 2013
Subject: FW: Challengage - Work Team Simulation product for interviewing evaluations
To: "Paul Klopfer (paul@challengage.com)" <paul@challengage.com>


Paul,
 This is the message below that I receive when I reply to your emails that come from this address: paul@challengage.herokuapp.com



David C. DiMaggio
Program Manager
CASE Co-op Program
Syracuse University
Center for Science & Technology
Room 1-232
Syracuse, NY 13244-4100
315-443-5018; Fax 315-443-4745
Cell: 315-436-1124
http://case.syr.edu/coops/index.php



-----Original Message-----
From: Mail Delivery Subsystem [mailto:MAILER-DAEMON@smtp2.syr.edu]
Sent: Monday, July 15, 2013 2:08 PM
To: David DiMaggio
Subject: Undeliverable: FW: Challengage - Work Team Simulation product for interviewing evaluations

Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:

paul@challengage.herokuapp.com
The server has tried to deliver this message, without success, and has stopped trying. Please try sending this message again. If the problem continues, contact your helpdesk.


The following organization rejected your message: challengage.herokuapp.com.









Diagnostic information for administrators:

Generating server: smtp2.syr.edu

paul@challengage.herokuapp.com
challengage.herokuapp.com #<challengage.herokuapp.com #4.4.7> #SMTP#

Original message headers:

Return-Path: <ddimaggi@syr.edu>
Received: from suex10-hub-01.ad.syr.edu ([128.230.108.124])
        by smtp2.syr.edu (8.14.5/8.14.5) with ESMTP id r68GaQdR008193
        (version=TLSv1/SSLv3 cipher=AES128-SHA bits=128 verify=FAIL);
        Mon, 8 Jul 2013 12:36:26 -0400
Received: from SUEX10-MBX-09.ad.syr.edu ([128.230.108.192]) by
 suex10-hub-01.ad.syr.edu ([128.230.108.124]) with mapi id 14.03.0123.003;
 Mon, 8 Jul 2013 12:36:26 -0400
From: David DiMaggio <ddimaggi@syr.edu>
To: "'Paul Klopfer'" <paul@challengage.herokuapp.com>
CC: "'Hendrickson, Cindy (GE Corporate)'" <lucinda.hendrickson@ge.com>
Subject: RE: FW: Challengage - Work Team Simulation product for interviewing
 evaluations
Thread-Topic: FW: Challengage - Work Team Simulation product for
 interviewing evaluations
Thread-Index: AQHOcuA7MvWUIninI0ObOEkuTugrYJlSpdKAgAhmsmA=
Date: Mon, 8 Jul 2013 16:36:25 +0000
Message-ID: <832C225B54BD58489EF60E1B2B7D1165264525@SUEX10-mbx-09.ad.syr.edu>
References: <832C225B54BD58489EF60E1B2B7D11652618DF@SUEX10-mbx-09.ad.syr.edu>
        <832C225B54BD58489EF60E1B2B7D1165261BF0@SUEX10-mbx-09.ad.syr.edu>
        <CAHGmi1POvrk1F954ViRL5xEHKDqN1sqFvqk6XWMH=U12VjO3PA@mail.gmail.com>
 <CAHGmi1Ofb13g7MenaT4Q69VJ=wU8fJcMdDpWih9P4tMC_4nsJA@mail.gmail.com>
In-Reply-To: <CAHGmi1Ofb13g7MenaT4Q69VJ=wU8fJcMdDpWih9P4tMC_4nsJA@mail.gmail.com>
Accept-Language: en-US
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Has-Attach:
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
x-originating-ip: [128.230.32.54]
Content-Type: text/plain
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Proofpoint-Virus-Version: vendor=fsecure engine=2.50.10432:5.10.8794,1.0.431,0.0.0000
 definitions=2013-07-08_02:2013-07-08,2013-07-08,1970-01-01 signatures=0
X-Proofpoint-Spam-Details: rule=notspam policy=default score=0 spamscore=0 suspectscore=0 phishscore=0
 adultscore=0 bulkscore=0 classifier=spam adjust=0 reason=mlx scancount=1
 engine=7.0.1-1305240000 definitions=main-1307080139
```

Answer (score 0):

You've configured the wrong from address in the outgoing transaction e-mails from your Heroku app.

You have a valid e-mail configuration on `chalengage.com` and a heroku app `challengage.herokuapps.com` that can't receive email.

You need to change your outgoing email address to `paul@challengage.com`

In Rails, you can configure the outgoing e-mail from address in your `ApplicationMailer`  class (subclasses `ActionMailer::Base`) by adding/changing the `default from` configuration:

```
default from: "Paul Klopfer <paul@challengage.com>"
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks Winfield! Do you know where in the App this would be configured. To clarify and confirm, this does not happen all the time. This only happens when certain people recieve emails from us and send emails to us.

Comment: Added a comment with more details.